# Why does a Django query that looks for an object with a specific id is slower on a large DB than on a smaller one?

Tags: sql, django, performance

Why does a query like this:

```
MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
```

run slower, even by a little bit, on a very large DB table than on a small DB table?. (e.g 10 row table vs 1 million row table)

Is it clearly SQL related or is it caused by the software that handles the query (in this case, Django)?

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't "handle the query". It actually runs the necessary SQL commands to search for the given object.

> Is it clearly SQL related or is it caused by the software that handles the query (in this case, Django)?

Well, it's not so simple. With a large database, a lot of things start to factor in. For example, how good is your hardware. How fast is your disk and CPU, how much RAM, etc.

That is why when your database grows and you start to see performance hit, you need to cache the database, or at least the frequently accessed objects, in RAM. If RAM is too expensive or can't be upgraded anymore, there's another technique called *Sharding*, which is basically spreading the database in multiple servers.

I'm sure doing a google search will yield plenty of detailed articles about optimizing db performance.

Comment: Thank you! Also, from what I have found out over the past few days, indexing plays a big part in how quickly the query is going to get executed. 
What triggered my question in the first place was my false assumption that every .get(id=x) operation is O(1) in every DB regardless of their size.